# Firebase. Нужен ли backend

Tags: firebase

Backend всегда разрабатывал на python, golang. Наткнулся на Firebase и не совсем понимаю, способен ли данный сервис заменить серверную сторону приложения или же это лишь замена базы данных?

Логику серверной стороны, как я понял можно разрабатывать с использованием Firebase Cloud Functions.
Звучит фантастически круто, если я все верно понял. Или есть какие-то подводные камни? Почему большинство компаний не использует данный вариант, в чем нужда в 2021 разрабатывать полноценный backend?

Comment: Подводные камни такие, что нельзя нормально сделать выборку с базы по нескольким критериям. Не советую для чего-то среднего и большого использовать. Ну и ограничения бесплатные.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас пишу на флаттере, и активно использую фб как бек.
Все начинается с описания правил доступа к бд. https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules
Чаще всего надо создавать 2 приложения. Один для администрации базы данных с полным доступом к бд. Второй для юзеров с ограниченными правами которые описаны по 'rules'. Для каких-то сложных сервисов это конечно не подойдет, но 90% требований для фронта покрывает. + можно легко можно подключиться прослушивать обновления определенной коллекции, из-за чего создавать чаты на фб становиться очень легко.

Comment: Взяв за пример Instagram приложение. Для реализации такой идеи Firebase подойдет или будут костыльные решения?

Comment: для основных функций сойдет. если прям 1 в 1 то точно нет)

Comment: а чего например не хватает?